# Default values for EF Core with enum to string Value Conversion

Tags: c#, .net, enums, entity-framework-core

EF Core 2.1+ supports [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions). You can use the built-in `EnumToStringConverter<>` to automatically convert an Enum to string, and vice versa.

I'm connecting to an existing database and would like one of the columns to be converted to an Enum, so `EnumToStringConverter<>` seems to be right up my alley. However, the database is also outside of my control (I only have read access) so what happens if anyone inserts a row into the table with a string value that does not match any of my enum definitions?

Preferrably I would like any unknown values to be mapped to an `Unknown` enum value, but I can't find any documentation on how to do this other than to manually create my own `ValueConverter` object where I implement my own manual parsing of all string values and map them to the appropriate enum value. This seems a bit cumbersome and adds additional maintenance, so I would very much like to have some automation here... meaning that if an unknown string value is found in the database, EFCore automatically maps this to my custom `Unknown` enum value.

Is this possible?

Comment: Should it be an enum if its values are not consistent? I mean imagine having an enum for week days Monday,Tuesday and etc. as there wont be more, but having an enum for something that is changing does not make sense. Though you still can do it.

Comment: The values will probably not change very often, but they might... so I need to handle that. And the type is a sort of a limited global product type, and these do not usually change in my scenario, but a new one might appear in a year, and it would be nice if my solution didn't crash when that happens.

Comment: There is no solution without programming. You make up the "create your own value converter" a little. an Enum.TryParse(out value) ?  value : enum.unknown is a one-liner.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm in the same situation and I am thinking I'm going to just either a) have to manually parse strings myself on the client side after queries or b) create a separate table for entities representing the enum values and enter them via EntityTypeBuilder.HasData statements.  Neither solution sounds very attractive

Answer (score 2):

(Improving on vsarunov's answer, which, as mentioned in the comments, doesn't work)
If you do the parsing in a separate method:

```
private MyEnumType ParseEnum(string input)
{
    if (Enum.TryParse<MyEnumType>(input, true, out var res))
        return res;

    return default;
}
```

Then you can use it in your converter:

```
 entity.Property(e => e.MyEnumField)
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .HasConversion(
                v => v.ToString(),
                v => ParseEnum(v));
```

---

You might prefer, especially if you need to convert several enum types, creating a generic extension method to do the parsing:

```
public static T ToEnum<T>(this string input) where T : struct
{
    if (Enum.TryParse<T>(input, true, out var res))
        return res;
    return default;
}
```

Then in your converter:

```
 entity.Property(e => e.MyEnumField)
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .HasConversion(
                v => v.ToString(),
                v => v.ToEnum<MyEnumType>());
```

Answer (score -2):

If I understand you correctly this should do the trick:

```
 entity.Property(e => e.MyEnumField)
        .HasMaxLength(50)
        .HasConversion(
                v => v.ToString(),
                v => {


                if(Enum.TryParse(v,true,out var res)){
                return res;
                }

                return MyEnum.Default;

                })
               .IsUnicode(false);
```

I have not tested this.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8

https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/44262314/how-can-i-make-ef-core-database-first-use-enums-

Comment: This approach will not work.  In fact, it won't even compile.  At least not under VS2019 version 16.4.5.  

The error is "A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree".  My guess is that EF Core cannot convert it to server-side eval.

I am in the same boat as @GTHVidsten and just tried it.